# Reaon of BrokenProcessPool error message while using concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor()?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to run this following code on Jupyter notebook (using Python 3.7.5) :

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something(seconds):
    print(f'sleeping for {seconds} seconds')
    time.sleep(seconds)
    return 'done sleeping'

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [executor.submit(do_something, 1) for _ in range(10)]    
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(results):
        print(f.result())

finish = time.perf_counter()

print(f'finished in  {round(finish-start,9)} seconds')
```

But, the interpreter shows an error message :

> BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.

I am learning multiprocessing from an YouTube tutorial where this code works fine. I haven't found any webpage discussing this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is correct; however it will not work in Jupyter.
Its expected behaviour according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor):

> The **main** module must be importable by worker subprocesses. This
> means that ProcessPoolExecutor will not work in the interactive
> interpreter.

Comment: Just tried it with python console and got the same error

Comment: Post a new question then.

Comment: Im getting this error for code like this one and running in idle why is that?

Comment: I was using parallel in loop and ofc in idle